# Puzzle Game QML GridView Animation Problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch, games, qt, qml, animations

I've been working on a puzzle game for Ubuntu Touch and I'm facing some issues with animations. The problem seems to occurs when GridView animations (add, move, remove...) play too fast.

Something like that it is explained here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-viewtransition.html#handling-interrupted-animations

I've been trying to solve that issue, but without success... I'd love any help on that. Is there any QML Ninja could help me ?

links:

There is an early presentation of this game here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1-V52DWwYk

The source code is on GitHub: github.com/jdorleans/matching-tux﻿

Comment: It's not an answer, but there's a samegame qml example on the Qt site.  Possibly look at how they implemented the same functionality and see if the problem evidences for you using their implementation of the same with different graphics.